# Determine whether the operator $A: C[-1,1] \to C[-1,1], Ax(t) = .5[x(t)+x(-t)]$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis

I have no idea how to approach any of these types of questions.  I would appreciate if anyone's answer could outline a general way to approach proving if an operator is compact.  I know that there are two ways you can show it.  The first is showing that $A$ maps bounded sets into precompact ones.  The second way is showing that any sequence has a convergent subsequence. I have had zero luck in this example or another one using these methods.

Comment: Wish to show $(x_n)_n$ bounded implies $(Ax_n)_n$ has a convergent subsequence. Say $|x_n(t)| \le M$ for each $n \ge 1$ and $t \in [-1,1]$. Since the subset of $C[-1,1]$ consisting of functions that are at most $M$ is compact, we can extract a convergent subsequence: say $(x_{n_k})_k \to x$. Then $Ax_{n_k}$ converges to $Ax$, so we're done.

Comment: @mathworker21 What you wrote makes sense, but I'm struggling to apply it to the other examples I have.  Would you mind helping me out with this one too? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224060/determine-whether-this-operator-is-compact

Comment: @mathworker21 Your statement that uniformly bounded sets in $C[-1,1]$ are compact is blatantly false.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oops, I was thinking about topology of pointwise convergence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n(t)=t^{2n}$. Then $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in $C[-1,1]$ and $Ax_n(t)=t^{2n}$. No subsequence of this sequence can converge uniformly since the pointwise limit is not continuous. Hence $A$ is not compact.