# Determine whether this operator is compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Define
$$A:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]\quad\text{by}\quad Au(x) = u\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + \int_0^1K(x,y)u(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$ where K has continuous first derivatives in both variables.  Is $A$ compact?

I have no idea how to approach any of these types of questions.  I would appreciate if anyone's answer could outline a general way to approach proving if an operator is compact.  I know that there are two ways you can show it.  The first is showing that $A$ maps bounded sets into precompact ones.  The second way is showing that any sequence $(x_n)$ yeilds a convergent sequence $(Ax_n)$. I have had zero luck in this example or another one using these methods.

Answer (score 1):

Take $K  \equiv 0$. The operator $u \to u(\frac x 2)$ is not compact; if it is compact you can easily see that the unit ball of $C[0,1]$ is compact which is false.